# Swift - Update multiple viewControllers

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I would like to update several views, at the same time.

In my app, you can change your name. When the user change its name,  would like to update 4 `ViewControllers`, to show the new name.
I use to use `delegates` to update one `ViewController`, but given that I would like to update more than 1, I don't think that's possible. (Maybe I'm wrong?)

I've heard about `NotificationCenter`, but I don't know if it's the best way to achieve that.
Something like that:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reload(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "uploaded"), object: nil)
```

Is it good to do that?

What do you think? How would you do this?

Comment: If all the view's are inside the same `ViewController` then i don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: @Kamran I'm really sorry about that, it's viewControllers and not views

Comment: Good to know. In this case then i think you can use `viewWillAppear` method of those viewControllers to update the name label.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do that, this depends on how your project struct.

If all views are in the same `ViewController` you can just listen some delegate and update manually all views, like, `self.view1.updateName(newName)`, `self.view2.updateName(newName)`

else if you have many `ViewControllers` you can do something like `Singleton` and get the name when `viewWillAppear`, (I prefer don't use `Singleton`)

Example

```
class MyInfo{
    public static let shared = MyInfo();

    private(set) var name:String?

    private init(){}

    func update(name:String){
        self.name = name;
    }
}
```

And on your `viewWillAppear` you can do something like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    self.label.text = MyInfo.shared.name;
}
```

I like so much flux pattern, with ReSwift, but I think it can be very complex for a small problem in your case.

I hope was helpful